# select2 options list largerly hidden in Foundation modal

Tags: zurb-foundation, jquery-select2

I'm using select2 in my website, and I'm already aware of the issue with modals. This is the script I use for initiating the select2 field:

```
  $(function() {
    $('#id_creator').djangoSelect2({
      dropdownParent: $('#addWorkFromEventForm'),
      width: '100%'})
  })
```

It works fine; nevertheless, the autocomplete list is almost completely hidden outside the modal. I've already set the z-index higher than the overlay's, and it doesn't seem to make any difference. Is there a solution to this? Or, can it at least be opened upwards instead of downwards, as a workaround?

[image]

**PS**

setting `data-overlay="false"` also doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by adding

```
display: table;
```

to the CSS properties of the modal.

Comment: @Zack Heisenberg I have to wait two days.

Comment: `<div id="new_dialog" style="position: unset;">` table didn't work but unset did